# Move a NSWindow by dragging a NSView

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa, nsview, nswindow

I have a NSWindow, on which i apply this:

```
window.styleMask = window.styleMask | NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask
window.titleVisibility = NSWindowTitleVisibility.Hidden;
window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true;
```

I then add a NSView behind the titlebar to simulate a bigger one.
Now it looks like this:
[image: Current window]

I want to be able to move the window, by dragging the light-blue view. I have already tried to subclass NSView and always returning true for mouseDownCanMoveWindow using this code:

```
class LSViewD: NSView {
    override var mouseDownCanMoveWindow:Bool {
        get {
            return true
        }
    }
}
```

This didn't work.
After some googling i found this [INAppStoreWindow](https://github.com/indragiek/INAppStoreWindow) on GitHub. However it doesn't support OS X versions over 10.9, so it's completely useless for me.

*Edit1*

This is how it looks in the Interface Builder.
[image: Interface Builder]

How can i move the window, by dragging on this NSView?

Comment: Solved it by myself, check out my answer.

Answer (score 26):

None of the answers here worked for me. They all either don't work at all, or make the whole window draggable (note that OP is not asking for this).

Here's how to actually achieve this:

**To make a NSView control the window with it's drag events, simply subclass it and override the `mouseDown` as such:**

```
class WindowDragView: NSView {

    override public func mouseDown(with event: NSEvent) {
        window?.performDrag(with: event)
    }

}
```

That's it. The `mouseDown` function will transfer further event tracking to it's parent window.

No need for window masks, `isMovableByWindowBackground` or `mouseDownCanMoveWindow`.

Comment: This is the best answer. Not sure why overriding `mouseDownCanMoveWindow` doesn't seem to work as documented.

Comment: nice one, thanks!

Comment: How to do it in SwifUI?

Comment: If I click the left mouse button quickly and multiple times, the NSWindow shifts position slightly

Answer (score 17):

Try setting the window's `movableByWindowBackground` property to true.

Comment: This would work, but it also enables window-movement from the dark-blue view, which is not what i wanted. It should only allow window movement from the light-blue area.

Comment: Have you tried having the dark-blue view overriding `mouseDownCanMoveWindow` to return false? Or, if the dark-blue view is opaque (always completely fills its bounds), having it return true for it's `opaque` property?

Comment: Tried both, didn't work. Either everything moves the window, or just the area where the title bar should be (not the whole light-blue bar, look how i arranged it in the Interface Builder)

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do this. The first one would be to set the `NSTexturedBackgroundWindowMask` as well as the windows background color to the one of your view. This should work.

Otherwise you can take a look at this [Sample Code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/RoundTransparentWindow/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: Could you please elaborate how i should do this and what it does?

Comment: Should the NSTexturedBackgroundWindowMask be set on the window.stylemask property or somewhere else?

Comment: Exactly! After that you set window.backgroundColor to your blue one. Then the whole window will be blue, so you need a additional colored view as the content view

Comment: This allowed me to remove the custom-view behind the titlebar, but didn't solve my problem. The window is still only draggable inside the titlebar frame. If i enable .movableByWindowBackground, the content view is also able to move the window. I tried turning this off via overriding the mouseDownCanMoveWindow and opaque property, without any success.

Comment: That is interesting, because it worked for me. Then try the Apple Sample code with your custom view. They track the mouseDown in the view and move the window accordingly

Answer (score 0):

I somehow managed to solve my problem, i don't really know how, but here are some screenshots.

[image]
[image]
[image]

In the AppDelegate file where i edit the properties of my window, i added an IBOutlet of my contentView. This IBOutlet is a subclass of NSView, in which i've overriden the variable mouseDownCanMoveWindow so it always returns false.

I tried this before in only one file, but it didn't work. This however solved the problem.

Thanks to [Ken Thomases](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1312143/ken-thomases) and [Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4113940/max) for leading me into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift3.0 Version**

```
override func viewDidAppear() {

    //for hide the TitleBar
    self.view.window?.styleMask = .borderless
    self.view.window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
    self.view.window?.titleVisibility = .hidden

    //for Window movable with NSView
    self.view.window?.isMovableByWindowBackground = true

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 3:

### I needed this but dynamically. It's a little long but well worth it (IMHO).

So I decided to enable this *only* while the command key is down.  This is achieved by registering a local key handler in the delegate:

```
// MARK:- Local key monitor
var localKeyDownMonitor : Any? = nil
var commandKeyDown : Bool = false {
    didSet {
        let notif = Notification(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "commandKeyDown"),
                                 object: NSNumber(booleanLiteral: commandKeyDown))
        NotificationCenter.default.post(notif)
    }
}

func keyDownMonitor(event: NSEvent) -> Bool {
    switch event.modifierFlags.intersection(.deviceIndependentFlagsMask) {

    case [.command]:
        self.commandKeyDown = true
        return true

    default:
        self.commandKeyDown = false
        return false
    }
}
```

which is enabled within the delegate startup:

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {     
    //  Watch local keys for window movenment, etc.
    localKeyDownMonitor = NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: NSEventMask.flagsChanged) { (event) -> NSEvent? in
        return self.keyDownMonitor(event: event) ? nil : event
    }
}
```

and its removal

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {  
    //  Forget key down monitoring
    NSEvent.removeMonitor(localKeyDownMonitor!)
}
```

Note that when the commandKeyDown value is changed by the key down handler.  This value change is caught by the didset{} to post a notification.  This notification is registered by any view you wish to have its window so moved - i.e., in the view delegate

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //  Watch command key changes
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(ViewController.commandKeyDown(_:)),
        name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "commandKeyDown"),
        object: nil)
}
```

and discarded when the viewWillDisappear() (delegate) or the window controller windowShouldClose(); add this

```
    <your-view>.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "commandKeyDown")
```

So sequence goes like this:

1. key pressed/release
2. handler called
3. notification posted

The view's window isMovableByWindowBackground property is changed by notification - placed within view controller / delegate or where you registered the observer.

```
internal func commandKeyDown(_ notification : Notification) {
    let commandKeyDown : NSNumber = notification.object as! NSNumber
    if let window = self.view.window {
        window.isMovableByWindowBackground = commandKeyDown.boolValue
        Swift.print(String(format: "command %@", commandKeyDown.boolValue ? "v" : "^"))
    }
}
```

Remove the tracer output when happy.  See it in action in [SimpleViewer](https://github.com/slashlos/SimpleViewer) on github.